# Binding resize event handler to table row with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I wonder if it's possible to bind a resize event handler to a table's row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and no, yes, but not by *default*.  There is however a plugin to support this by [Ben Alman - the jQuery resize event plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/), which allows `resize` on more than just `window`.

[You can test out a demonstration of it with a `<tr>` here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/FLw3r/).