# Flexigrid / resizable row height dynamically

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services, flexigrid

Check this image for before starting : [Grid Image](http://postimage.org/image/gthl3j5nn/)
 [image]

I'm using jQuery flexigrid and I want to resize the row heights dynamically. 
The user can resize the row heights at runtime and save the heights in database and next time the changed height will be applied.

I need some ideas on where to start or an example solution, it will be very helpful to start my work.

My development environment is : ASP.NET, C# ,jQuery and Web services.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, user. This question is much better than the one you just removed. This is very salvageable. Consider using the **edit** button below the question to add more details, code, things you've tried, and other things that may help the community help you find an answer. I'm sure you'll find our community can be quite friendly and helpful when you add those details :) Good luck in finding an answer to your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you should customize the original flexigrid code. 
here is the general steps I think we can follow.

1. Should add the resize feature to the `tr` of the table. because the flexigrid use `html table` to display. here is the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439026/binding-resize-event-handler-to-table-row-with-jquery) to make it .
2. Should add a json or other format to store the `Row` definition.
3. Customize the render functon of the flexigrid to add css style to the `tr` against the json which stored in the DB .